# Parse variables from local JSON file in vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to get access to stored values from local JSON files.

I load the JSON via

```js
let json_url = "./static/" + captureMode + ".json";
let jsondata = {};
await fetch(json_url)
 .then(response => response.json())
 .then(data => jsondata = data);
```

But when trying to parse via `let parsedData = JSON.parse(jsondata);`
I get the error "Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: "[object Object]" is not valid JSON".

Edit:
Also directly trying to access values from `jsondata` after `response.json()` does result in an undefined output.
Does anybody have an idea what's happening?

EDIT:

The JSON looks like this:

```js
{
    "CameraSettings": {
        "rawOnOff": true,
        "shutter": 10000,
        "autoWhiteBalance": false,
        "exposureMode": "normal",
        "exposure": 0,
        "gains1": 1.6,
        "gains2": 1.5,
        "width": 4500,
        "height": 3600,
        "filename": "Before_Val_",
        "counter": 0,
        "sharpness": 1,
        "contrast": 1,
        "brightness": 50,
        "saturation": 0,
        "videoBitrate": 100,
        "videoFPS": 16.666,
        "videoLength": 1000,
        "accuracy": 100000,
        "framecount": 1,
        "offset": 0,
        "skipped_frames": 0
    }
}
```

Comment: How does your jsondata look like?

Comment: { "CameraSettings": {
        "rawOnOff": true,
        "shutter": 10000,
        "autoWhiteBalance": false,
        "exposureMode": "normal",
        "exposure": 0,
        "gains1": 1.6,
        "gains2": 1.5,
        "width": 4500,
        "height": 3600,
        "filename": "Before_Val_",
        "counter": 0,
        "sharpness": 1,
        "contrast": 1
        }
}

Comment: Add this to the question too, you can edit it. So others can see it easier. But this already looks like json to me on first glance?

Comment: **It's just a typo-level error**. *"But when trying to parse via let parsedData = JSON.parse(jsondata); I get the error "Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: "[object Object]" is not valid JSON"."* When you do `response.json()`, the promise it returns is fulfilled when the body text has been read **and** parsed. So you don't want to do `JSON.parse(jsondata)`; `jsondata` (which will want renaming) is **already** parsed, it's already an object. So passing it into `JSON.parse` (which requires a string) does the implicit conversion to string, which gives you the string `"[object Object]"`.

Comment: More in MDN's documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/json Side note: You should check that the HTTP request worked (sadly, there's a footgun in the `fetch` API -- it only rejects its promise on *network* errors, not HTTP errors). I have a writeup about it on my anemic old blog [here](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2018/06/common-fetch-errors.html).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks! I thought that might be the case, but then I get an undefined error when trying to access keys/values via something like `console.log(jsondata.CameraSettings.rawOnOff)` (or versions of it) .

Comment: @TooLongDin'tRead - That would mean the data isn't as you expected. If you read the JSON you've provided, [it works just fine](https://jsfiddle.net/tjcrowder/0p6htw8o/).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder By now I think I had a typo in the key/value description (data.class.key). 
Trying to access bools resulted in "undefined". It works since I rewrote a section. 
Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `jsondata` is already the parsed object, as `response.json()` will [parse the responsed JSON text](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/json). You may just use `jsondata` as `parsedData`.

Besides, it's really strange and unclear to use `await` and `Promise.prototype.then()` at the same time. I think the code can be improved to:

```
let response = await fetch(json_url);
let parsedData = await response.json();
```

Comment: @TooLongDin'tRead Well, you can read more about `await` feature and compare it with promise methods on [MDN here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await). Please accept my answer if it is helpful.